# 100% 2 Column Height CSS Problem!

Tags: css, height

I'm using this [layout](http://layouts.ironmyers.com/100_percent_Layouts/layout/?id=5) to create a 2 column fluid web page.

What I can't seem to do is make it so that both the columns in the layout have a height of 100% therefore pushing the footer to the bottom of the page!

Whats the best way to achieve this effect?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hopefully this is what you're looking for:

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-2-column-right-menu.htm

Answer (score 7):

Last time I read about this the best answer was `display: table;` for the main container and  `display: table-cell;` for each column. This will make the column the height that you specify.

```css
#wrap {
  background: orange;
  display: table;
  height: 88%;
  width: 550px;
  padding: 11px;
}
#col1 {
  display:table-cell;
  background: #808080;
  width: 222px;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  padding: 12px;
}
#col2 {
  display:table-cell;
  background: #808080;
  width: 111px;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!-- this container will determine the height of both columns --> 
<div id="wrap">

  <div id="col1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum something or other.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="col2">
    <p>More Lorem than ipsum.</p>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- end container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a different layout, why waste your time trying to hack a cross-browser solution?
This seems to be what you need, but I'm sure you can find others: http://www.savio.no/examples/three-column-layout-6.asp

Answer (score 0):

I do the following in my personal site's CSS [file](http://warrenmyers.com/main.css):

```
#footer
{width: 100%;
bottom: 0px;
padding-top: .5em;
padding-bottom: .5em;
background-color: #ffffff;
border-top: 1px #000000 solid;
text-align: center;
margin-top: .25em;
}
```

Also, I have little in the way of nested `div` tags. I prefer to have the elements float around each other.

Answer (score 0):

have 2 div tags, each as a column floating next to each other, and another div tag to clear the floats, then lastly another div to be the footer:

```
<div id="col1"></div>
<div id="col2"></div>
<div clear="c"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
<style type="text/css"><!--
#col1{
   float:left;
   width:80%;
}
#col2{
   float:right;
   width:20%;
}
.c{
   clear:both;
}
#footer{}
--></style>
```

With this, it's also easier to make it a 3 column.

```
<div id="col1"></div>
<div id="col2"></div>
<div id="col3"></div>
<div clear="c"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
<style type="text/css"><!--
#col1{
   float:left;
   width:200px;
}
#col2{
   float:right;
   width:300px;
}
#col3{
   width:400px;
   margin-left:200px;
   margin-right:300px;
}
.c{
   clear:both;
}
#footer{}
--></style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way...

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="col1"></div>
    <div id="col2"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>

<style type="text/css"><!--
    body { height: 100% }
    #container { height: 100% }
    #col1 { height:100%; float:left; width: 70% }
    #col2 { height:100%; float:right; width: 30% }
    #footer { height: 50px; clear: both }
--></style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just made [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexche8/8VkLC/6/embedded/result/) by Matthew James Taylor [post](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks). For me it was very useful. I think this is not a problem to remade for two column.

```
<div id="container3">
<div id="container2">
    <div id="container1">
        <div id="col1"><p>Column 1</p>
            <p>Nunc egestas, vut mus hac diam lacus lacus nisi odio,
               turpis dictumst   mattis! Turpis ac ut nec nec et augue, in nec turpis 
               hac quis risus vel risus pid ridiculus purus urna ultrices ac turpis. In,    
               magna odio mattis! Ultricies? Odio nec odio enim porta urna phasellus 
               proin in lacus! Dignissim eros, ac duis porttitor dapibus et vel sed est?
               Nec placerat egestas, nunc rhoncus scelerisque sit sit, magna elementum 
               eu ac, montes dolor ultrices eros velit! Urna dignissim. Enim, aliquam ut    
               porta etiam amet dolor in natoque? Integer nunc? Magnis, auctor sit nunc 
               in nec, dictumst 
               pulvinar proin! In nisi pulvinar penatibus lorem nec, tempor porta 
               ultricies, et monte.a asdfjasdjfklasdfasdfljsdfkj</p>
        </div>
        <div id="col2">
            <p>Column 2 </p>
            <p>Nunc egestas, vut mus hac diam lacus lacus nisi odio,
               turpis dictumst   mattis! Turpis ac ut nec nec et augue, in nec turpis 
               hac quis risus vel risus pid ridiculus purus urna ultrices ac turpis. In,    
               magna odio mattis! Ultricies? Odio nec odio enim porta urna phasellus 
               proin in lacus! Dignissim eros, ac duis porttitor dapibus et vel sed est?
               Nec placerat egestas, nunc rhoncus scelerisque sit sit, magna elementum 
               eu ac, montes dolor ultrices eros velit! Urna dignissim. Enim, aliquam ut    
               porta etiam amet dolor in natoque? Integer nunc? Magnis, auctor sit nunc                                      
        </div>
        <div id="col3">Column 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

​

```
#container3 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:green;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
#container2 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:yellow;
    position:relative;
    right:30%;
}
#container1 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:red;
    position:relative;
    right:40%;
}
#col1 {
    float:left;
    width:26%;
    position:relative;
    left:72%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#col2 {
    float:left;
    width:36%;
    position:relative;
    left:76%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#col3 {
    float:left;
    width:26%;
    position:relative;
    left:80%;
    overflow:hidden;
}​
```

Answer (score -1):

Try : `overflow:hidden;` on the wrap .
Hope That Helps